# Telerik or Devexpress scheduler

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, telerik, devexpress, scheduler

We have got a requirement to use a scheduler in one of our application. After browsing we found some tools to do this.

We found two main third party components for this - **Telerik Scheduler** and **Devexpress scheduler.**

We need another functionality like we need to drag some data from another control to this scheduler.

So both these gives this option

For Telerik :  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/draganddropintegration/defaultcs.aspx

For Devexpress : http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2274

So for this functionality which one is better; i can't find any exact comparison for the scheduler components of both products.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective question but both control are decent and have great support and rich feature set. My advise would be to get a trial of both and see how it matches to your liking, general design and what you're trying to achieve with it.